# How to Find whether the given string is present in the NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I have a  `NSString =@"KEY3";` and a `NSMutableDictionary *AllValues ;` like the below . I just need to check whether the string is one of the element of the AllValues Dictionary

```
KEY1 {
    MLCAvailable = "test";
    MLCColorCode = "test2";
     NotesCount = "test3";
     },
KEY2 {
    MLCAvailable = "test";
    MLCColorCode = "test2";
     NotesCount = "test3";
     },
KEY3 {
    MLCAvailable = "test";
    MLCColorCode = "test2";
     NotesCount = "test3";
     },
KEY4 {
    MLCAvailable = "test";
    MLCColorCode = "test2";
     NotesCount = "test3";
     },

How should i find whether they KEY 3 is present in the given MutableDictionary ?
```

Comment: if ([AllValues objectForKey:@"KEY3"]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it with the help of for loop

```
 for (NSString *strKey in [AllValues allKeys]) {

            if ([strKey isEqualToString:@"KEY3"]) {
                //your condition
            }
        }
```

Is it Helpfull?

Answer (score 4):

You can just try and get the element...

```
if(AllValues[@"KEY3"]) {
   //The element exists
}
```